# Can you do if/else logic in MYSQL statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I have football players in a database.  They each have a ranking (1 is best) and I calculate their age on the fly in the MYSQL query.  That query does an ORDER BY using their ranking plus their age.  So I first have this...

```
$rankquerytext="ranking + age";
```

Then I have the query...

```
$sql = "SELECT *, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), born) / 365.25) AS age 
    FROM players
    ORDER BY " . $rankquerytext . "";
```

This works just fine.  However, I'd like to get a little more specific than just adding their age to their ranking.  For example, I'd prefer to do an if/else either in the MySQL query somehow, or just before it, such as...

```
if (age < 25) {
$ageadjustment=-5;
} else if (age >= 29) {
$ageadjustment= 8;
} else {
$ageadjustment=0;
}
```

And then I'd like to add the "$ageadjustment" to their ranking, instead of the "age".

For example, when using "ranking + age", if Calvin Johnson is ranked #1, then his final ORDER BY figure is 30 (1 + 29).

Ideally, using "ranking + $ageadjustment", he would be 9 (1 + 8).

Is this doable?  I am limited in my mysql knowledge, but this doesn't seem doable.

Thanks

Comment: [mysql case statement](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/case-operator.php)

Comment: I wonder if you even googled this? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Comment: @rjdown you should put this as an answer!!! When did they put this into MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) operator as shown below:

```php
$rankquerytext = "ranking + adj";

$sql = "SELECT *,
 CASE WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), born) / 365.25) < 25 THEN -5 
 WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), born) / 365.25) >= 29 THEN 8
 ELSE 0 
 END AS adj 
 ORDER BY " . $rankquerytext;
```